# AdWhirlView: getting adWhirlConfigDidReceiveConfig callback from unknown AdWhirlConfig object

Tags: ios, admob, iad, adwhirl

I have navigation controller in my app. When my app launches then in firstViewController ads showing properly. When I select any row on firstViewController then I am pushing secondViewController. When secondViewController is loaded , I can see ad on secondViewController but in my console I am getting

```
AdWhirlView: getting adWhirlConfigDidReceiveConfig callback from unknown AdWhirlConfig object
```

Why this is happening I don't know. If anyone knows about this , kindly let me know. 
If you need see my code then let me know ,I will add my code .
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us some code showing how you are inserting ads into your first view controller and then how you are adding them into the second one that gets pushed on?

Comment: Are you modifying your AdWhirlConfig object in the AdWhirlView at any point? It looks like you're hitting adWhirlConfigDidReceiveConfig: but the AdWhirlConfig object coming back there isn't equal to the property set in the AdWhirlView.

Answer (score 0):

probably, you are realeasing another object first. Make sure you check your "autorelease". I've had weird results from autoreleasing something which had nothing to do with the whole adwhirl.